# atio6axx Access Violation when opening Minecraft

Tags: laptop, drivers, windows-11

A few days ago, I was prompted by tech support to update my BIOS for another issue I was experiencing with my docking station. While that problem has been fixed, I am now experiencing problems when opening Minecraft (haven't tried anything else). It tries to launch after clicking "Play" in the launcher and then crashes about 5 seconds later with Exit Code: 1. I've looked into the [crash report](https://justpaste.it/9xke5) and it seems to be a problem with atio6axx, which I've found online to be the graphics driver.

I have updated my [AMD VGA Driver](https://pcsupport.lenovo.com/us/en/products/laptops-and-netbooks/5-series/ideapad-5-pro-16ach6/82l5/82l5000xus/yx02mhbr/downloads/ds552368-amd-vga-driver-for-windows-11-64-bit-ideapad-creator-5-16ach6-ideapad-5-pro-16ach6?category=Graphics%20Processing%20Units%20%28GPU%29%20and%20Server-AI%20Accelerators) as well as my [AMD Chipset Driver](https://pcsupport.lenovo.com/us/en/products/laptops-and-netbooks/5-series/ideapad-5-pro-16ach6/82l5/82l5000xus/yx02mhbr/downloads/ds552367-amd-chipset-driver-for-windows-11-64-bit-ideapad-creator-5-16ach6-ideapad-5-pro-16ach6?category=Motherboard%20Devices%20%28core%20chipset,%20onboard%20video,%20PCIe%20switches%29) from the Lenovo website in hopes that it would fix the issue (because that's what I've seen as suggested troubleshooting online in similar problems), but the problem is still present. Any ideas?